# No module named PIL after installing Pillow (v5.2.0) with pip v18.0

Tags: python, pip, compression, python-imaging-library

As the title says, after I installed Pillow with `pip install Pillow`, when I'm trying to import it "No module named 'PIL' " error appears.
I'm trying to import it with this code: `from PIL import ImageTk, Image`.
I have pip 18.0 installed, and Pillow 5.2.0.
I'm using just `python 3.7`.
I have to mention that I don't have PIL installed.
After trying with `easy_install` and `python -m pip install`, still don't work.

`python -m pip install` returns: 
`Collecting pillow Downloading files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/22/… (1.4MB) 100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.4MB 2.6MB/s Installing collected packages: pillow Successfully installed pillow-5.2.0`
Command `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` returns: 
`['', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\python37.zip', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\DLLs', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'c:\\users\\lenovo b590\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']`

Maybe helps: I have VS 2017 installed with C++ and Python. I'v tryed to install python-pptx and got error: 
`Command ""c:\users\lenovo b590\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\LENOVO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-_o4pnv9h\\lxml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-08vt5tx4\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\LENOVO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_o4pnv9h\lxml\`

Comment: Do you have only one python version installed?

Comment: Odd, it looks like your setup is correct as far as I can tell. Is there more to the `no Module named PIL` error message?

Comment: No, is the single error in that file... and it just says that.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: C:\Users\Lenovo B590\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\Pillow-5.2.0.dist-info

Comment: and if i search PIL: C:\Users\Lenovo B590\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\PIL

Comment: Where and how have you tried to run the line `from PIL import ...`?

Comment: I'v created a new file and added that code and it returns the same error.

Comment: Are you running the file through your IDE or using the command line (i.e. typing `python <filename>`?

Comment: I'm running it through the IDLE 3.6 (64-Bit)

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when running from the command line?

Comment: Hmmm, no! I think that's the answer... (python console 32 bit)

Comment: If I run that with IDLE 3.7 (32 bit) it works

Comment: Great to hear that it is figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running the code through IDLE 3.6 (64-Bit), running it through IDLE 3.7 (32-Bit) solved the problem, thanks to FlyingTeller !